# NodeJS failing to find routes

Tags: node.js, express

Updated `Server.js` code:

/Server.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.set('view engine', 'vash');
app.set('views', path.join( __dirname, '/views') );

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

var indexRoutes = require('./routes/index')
app.use('/', indexRoutes);

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

app.listen(3000);
console.log("yep >>> Server running on port 3000");
```

I'm still getting the same error not found

**END UPDATE**

I'm trying to setup routes in nodejs and its able to display the index.html page but when I click on about link I get the below error:
error:

> Error: Failed to lookup view "about" in views directory
>   "c:\nodejs\views"    at EventEmitter.app.render
>   (c:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:519:17)    at
>   ServerResponse.res.render
>   (c:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:933:7)    at
>   exports.about (c:\nodejs\routes\index.js:11:9)    at Layer.handle [as
>   handle_request]
>   (c:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)    at next
>   (c:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)    at
>   Route.dispatch
>   (c:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)    at
>   Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (c:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)    at
>   c:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22    at
>   Function.proto.process_params
>   (c:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)    at next
>   (c:\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)

/Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
//route
var routes = require('./routes');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.set('view engine', 'vash');

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/about', routes.about);
app.get('/contact', routes.contact);
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.listen(3000);
console.log("yep >>> Server running on port 3000");
```

/routes/index.js

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', year: new Date().getFullYear() });
};

exports.about = function (req, res) {
    res.render('about', { title: 'About', year: new Date().getFullYear(), message: 'Your application description page.' });
};

exports.contact = function (req, res) {
    res.render('contact', { title: 'Contact', year: new Date().getFullYear(), message: 'Your contact page.' });
};
```

here is the file structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about two things here:

1. How express serves template
2. How routing works

As far as  serving templates is concerned, best resource would be to read express official documentation about [res.render(..)](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render)

If you want  **vash** to be your default template engine then you should mention:

```
app.set('view engine', 'vash');
app.set('views', path.join( __dirname, '/views') );
```

Next is about serving the **.vash** files on routes.

Before that let me correct your route first.
If i understand correctly the following routes you want to implement:

1. http://localhost:3000/
2. http://localhost:3000/about
3. http://localhost:3000/contact

To do that you need to add these lines in **server.js**:

```
var indexRoutes = require('./routes/index')
app.use('/', indexRoutes);
```

You can change your ./routes/index.js file to :

```
    var router = express.Router();
    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.render('indexTpl', {title: 'Express', year: new Date().getFullYear()},            
         function(err, html) {
           // ...
         });
    });
    router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
      res.render('aboutTpl', { title: 'About', year: new Date().getFullYear(), message: 'Your application description page.' },            
         function(err, html) {
           // ...
         });
    });
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.render('contactTpl',{ title: 'Contact', year: new Date().getFullYear(), message: 'Your contact page.' },            
         function(err, html) {
           // ...
         });
    });
    module.exports = router;
```

*Please note i changed the name of templates to **indexTpl.vish, contactTpl.vish, aboutTpl.vish**. Before you run your program make sure you have those **.vish** files inside your **'views'** folder.*

***NOTE***: You can comment below mentioned three lines in server.js as we are using router in index.js file:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/about', routes.about);
app.get('/contact', routes.contact);
```

**Please see [this](https://github.com/kirbysayshi/vash-express-example) example for more understanding.**

Comment: I'm still getting the same error, I have updated my question with Server.js, please have a look

Comment: I think you have not read my answer properly, please read it again and update your project accordingly. It should work, if you still face problem then share your repository link, i will take a look and run it in my own system.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using the `.vash` filename extension for your views, you need to tell Express to look for `.html` and how to handle them by adding:

```
app.engine('html', require('vash').renderFile);
```

Comment: I have tried your approach but did not work, getting the same error, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your file extension wrong. Let's change to

```
index.vash
```

instead of

```
index.html
```